# How I Create Fix Number Of Rows In SQLite Table in Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I don't know SQLite Queries well, I don't know how to make fixed size rows in sqlite table. After full table rows value, I want to override first(Oldest) one and after that second and so on.. I made a table which I clear every day at 00AM but I think it is not a good coding practice. Please suggest me solution for how to do that.

Comment: So... simply update your fixed number of rows, instead of inserting new ones and deleting the old ones.

Comment: @DerGolem But what about _Id it is easy to delete it first but in future how i get what exactly i am going to delete.

Comment: refer this link i hope it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035670/limit-an-sqlite-tables-maximum-number-of-rows

Comment: Thanx @Rakesh i think, i got solution from these link.

Comment: Also see that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19033834/11654

Comment: @CL. Thanx you also give me second option. But i am confuse in that, is it good way for _Id ?

Comment: When you have an autoincrementing `_id` column, the smalles values are the oldest ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my Answer from @CL (Best Solution) & @Rakesh Thank you so much

> [linkFromCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024269/complex-trigger-on-sqlite/19033834#19033834) – From @CL.
>
> [linkFromRakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035670/limit-an-sqlite-tables-maximum-number-of-rows) –  From @Rakesh